# Problem with conditional rendering in React Native

Tags: react-native, conditional-rendering

I have a map and i want a marker to appear when the user long-presses on a point.
I have the following code:

```js
    const [coords, setcoords] = React.useState(getcoord());
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

    const setPointCoords = (e) => {
        setcoords(e.geometry.coordinates);
        setShow(!show);
    }

    return (
        <View style={style.page}>
            <MapboxGL.MapView
                style={style.map}
                rotateEnabled={false}
                styleURL="mapbox://styles/daskalgg/ckp26fbmb34iv18otkav9sj4s"
                onLongPress={(e) => {
                    setPointCoords(e);
                }}
            >
                {
                    show &&
                    <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                        key="marker"
                        id="point"
                        draggable={true}
                        coordinate={coords} />
                }
            </MapboxGL.MapView>
            {
                show &&
                <Text>test</Text>
            }
        </View>
    );
```

The problem i have is that, although setPointCoords is called and the value of show changes, the marker never appears.

Some things i have noticed:

1. The Text element, which is there for testing purposes, works as expected.
2. The problem goes away when the initial value of show is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but it's pretty hacky

```js
                <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                    key="marker"
                    id="point"
                    draggable={true}
                    onSelected={(e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    }}
                    coordinate={coords} >
                    <View
                        key="marker"
                        style={{
                            borderColor: "black", backgroundColor: "red",
                            display: show ? 'flex' : 'none'
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text> This is a Marker </Text>
                    </View>
                </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
```

Since i can't control the style of the PointAnnotation itself, i display a View and control it's visibility through 'show'. I am not accepting it as the correct answer yet in hopes there is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
{show ? (
   <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
     key="marker"
     id="point"
     draggable={true}
     coordinate={coords} 
   /> )
: null}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is because it doesn't seem like MapboxGL.PointAnnotation does well with child components rendering conditionally. Realized this with your answer you posted.